# Steering Behavior Pursuit quick question

Tags: steering-behaviors

In the code below, you will see Heading(). Is that just a position that is normalized? If not, then what is the heading?

```
Vector2D SteeringBehavior::Pursuit(const Vehicle* evader)

    {

      //if the evader is ahead and facing the agent then we can just seek

      //for the evader's current position.

      Vector2D ToEvader = evader->Pos() - m_pVehicle->Pos();



      double RelativeHeading = m_pVehicle->Heading().Dot(evader->Heading());



      if ( (ToEvader.Dot(m_pVehicle->Heading()) > 0) &&  

           (RelativeHeading < -0.95))  //acos(0.95)=18 degs

      {

        return Seek(evader->Pos());

      }



      //Not considered ahead so we predict where the evader will be.



      //the lookahead time is propotional to the distance between the evader

      //and the pursuer; and is inversely proportional to the sum of the

      //agent's velocities

      double LookAheadTime = ToEvader.Length() / 

                            (m_pVehicle->MaxSpeed() + evader->Speed());



      //now seek to the predicted future position of the evader

      return Seek(evader->Pos() + evader->Velocity() * LookAheadTime);

    }
```

Comment: So I think heading is just a angle that I can get with the function atan2.

Comment: You can see that they are using the dot product. Heading is a normalized vector.  Meaning that it's a direction. [if you place a normalized vector into a unit circle you can see that the x and y components give you cos and sin](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/images/unit-circle-xy.svg). You can get the angle with atan2 even if it's not normalized.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that just a position that is normalized?

Heading most likely implies a direction( which im certain of in this piece of code). But it's not a position but a Vector. Vectors don't have position. They describe direction and magnitude ( = length).

You can definitely define vectors from positions. The difference between two points is a vector with length and magnitude. A vector from a single point would look like a line from origin 0 to the point. Eventhough we can store a point in a vector, don't see vectors themselves as having a position. They describe direction and magnitude.

Edit:

To copy what I said in the comment

You can see that they are using the [dot product](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html). Heading is a normalized vector.  Meaning that it's a direction. [if you place a normalized vector into a unit circle you can see that the x and y components give you cos and sin](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/images/unit-circle-xy.svg). You can get the angle with atan2 even if it's not normalized. Point being that vectors and angles go hand in hand.

```
if(ToEvader.Dot(m_pVehicle->Heading()) > 0)
```

[This neat trick here is using the sign of the dot product to determine if something is in front or behind the heading](https://math.libretexts.org/@api/deki/files/1833/1.3.3.jpg?revision=1&size=bestfit&width=637&height=145)

like in the code the dot of 2 vectors give you a scalar ( a single number rather than a vector ) with which you can also tell an objects orientation without working with actual angles.